# Telebot. Как принять ввод внутри callback_query_handler?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Пишу телеграм-бота используя модуль **TeleBot**.

В теле функции обрабатываются нажатия на кнопки **InlineKeyboardMarkup**.
Но внутри нее есть условный блок: "если нажата, кнопка с **`callback_data = ok`**, то...", где в блоке **`else`** необходимо дождаться ввода от пользователя.

```html
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback(callback):
    if (callback.data == 'ok'):
        if not weekdays_list:
            bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Нажмите хотя бы одну кнопку.")
    else:
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Введите, пожалуйста, в какое время необходимо оповещать, в формате 'hhmm'.")
```

**Пробовал так:** (создавал в конце программы, перед **`bot.infinity_polling()`** функцию ***answer***)

```html
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback(callback):
    if (callback.data == 'ok'):
        if not weekdays_list:
            bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Нажмите хотя бы одну кнопку.")
    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Введите, пожалуйста, в какое время необходимо оповещать, в формате 'hhmm'.")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, answer)

def answer():
    print ('Ого, работает!')

bot.infinity_polling()
```

**И так:**

```html
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def answer(message):
    print ('Ого, работает!')

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback(callback):
    if (callback.data == 'ok'):
        if not weekdays_list:
            bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Нажмите хотя бы одну кнопку.")
    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Введите, пожалуйста, в какое время необходимо оповещать, в формате 'hhmm'.")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, answer)
```

**И еще так:**

```html
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback(callback):
    if (callback.data == 'ok'):
        if not weekdays_list:
            bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Нажмите хотя бы одну кнопку.")
    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Введите, пожалуйста, в какое время необходимо оповещать, в формате 'hhmm'.")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, answer)

        @bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
        def answer(message):
            print ('Ого, работает!')
```

Прошу подсказать, каким образом можно реализовать?

Спасибо за уделенное время!